# node.js installed but still getting complaints in RInno

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, shinydashboard

*node.js* was installed per the request of *RInno* when running for the first time. Now each time I run it, it still complains about it asking me whether I want to install. This happens, if I do not set the *user_browser* to *chrome* or *firefox*. And then, there is the warning I receive when I set it to *chrome*, saying that these will be deprecated, and the only option left will be *electron*.

So do I need to include node.js in environment variables, or do something else for this to work properly?

```
Error in nativefy_app(app_name, app_dir, nativefier_opts, app_icon = dots$app_icon) : 
  Change the user_browser to 'chrome', 'firefox' or 'ie' 
if you do not have Nodejs installed.


Warning message:
user_browser = "chrome" will be deprecated in the next release. 
Please use user_browser = "electron" in the future.
```

Comment: this is probably better suited as an issue on the github page: https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues. It looks like the node_exists function is not finding your installation of node.js for some reason.

Comment: I am having the same problem.. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @NBE Unfortunately no. I gave up afterward.